# calling javascript function from c++ node.js extension

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I have some javascript file and I want to call some function defined in this file during a call to my c++ function. Note that I want to call it by name, not just some random function passed as argument.

test.js:

```
function someFunc()
{
    // do something...
}

var my_module = require("my_native_module");
my_module.nativeFunc();
```

test.cpp:

```
using namespace v8;

Handle< Value > nativeFunc(const Arguments & args)
{
    HandleScope scope;
    // I want to somehow get someFunc value from current context by name
    Local< Value > function_value = Context::GetCurrent()->Global()->Get_By_Name(String::New("someFunc")); // this doesn't work
    //  probably check that function_value is really a function...
    Local< Function > function_callable = Local< Function >::Cast(function_value);
    function_callable->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 0, nullptr);
    return(scope.Close(Undefined()));
}
```

All the examples seem to accept the function as an argument (callback) like this:

```
Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);
```

But I need to find the function by name instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a quick example ready to test this, but was looking at some code that implies you should be able to do something like this:

```
  Handle<String> process_name = String::NewFromUtf8(GetIsolate(), "Foo");
  Handle<Value> process_val = context->Global()->Get(process_name);

  if (!process_val->IsFunction()) return false;

  Handle<Function> process_fun = Handle<Function>::Cast(process_val);

  process_fun->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 0, nullptr);
```

Comment: I'm using node.js v0.10.33 and v8::String doesn't have any NewFromUtf8 method. Looking at v8 documentation NewFromUtf8 is supposed to be there however it's not present in includes supplied along with node.js

Comment: `NewFromUtf8` is for node v 0.12.  `String::New("Whatevs")` is for older node.